# Pure HTML and CSS color flag does not work

Tags: html, css

When I go to browser to see the page it's showing nothing. Also there is no error.

HTML file name: flag.html

CSS file name: flag.css

```css
.red {
  background: red !important;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Comment: Your divs have no content, width, or height

Comment: Add a `height: 100px;` and `width: 100px;` to all the classes above.  Or just `div {height: 100px; width 100px; }` as an example.  Your Divs are just an empty `0px` x `0px` box right now ..

Comment: Thank you so much !! It works after adding height and width ! :)

Answer (score -2):

I believe the problem is that the div you are defining have no content in it (basically the div is empty)

So, you can either add content or specify the height and width of the div

```css
.red {
  background: red !important;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

div{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

simply you need to add a `height` and `width` to your `div` tags ,because by default they are just an empty tags with a 0 `height` and `width`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment !! It works after adding height and width ! :)